# Common storage for Chrome website and Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a Common storage for Chrome website and Chrome Extension. I have a Website. i stored Auth key in local storage. and also i developed chrome extension when i open the extension i want to access the local storage key as i already stored. Please let me know is this possible otherwise suggest some alternatives

I stored key in web like

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "XXXXX");
```

I want to access this key in chrome extension popup.js

Kindly Help me.

Comment: Did you try searching for [localStorage in the google-chrome-extension tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D+localStorage)?  Please explain how the information contained in the top results does not solve your problem so we can provide answers which are more targeted to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access localStorage (`localStorage.getItem('key')`) only from [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), but you can exchange data between `content script` and background/event scripts through [chrome messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) if you need.

Comment: incorrect answer. localStorage of content script is in a different context than the page.